# Use random inner product to test if at least one vector is uniform

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u$ and $v$ be two vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$.
Define a permutation of a vector $v':=\sigma(v)$ by $v'_j = v_{\sigma(j)}$ for any $\sigma \in S_n$.

It is easy to show the following for $u,v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ by considering $\sigma$ being a swap:

> $u = c\vec{1}$ or $v = c\vec{1}$ for some $c \in \mathbb{C} \iff $ $\langle u,\sigma(v) \rangle$ is invariant for any $\sigma \in S_n$.

I am wondering if the following is also true:

> Let $n \geq 3$. $u = c\vec{1}$ or $v = c\vec{1}$ for some $c \in \mathbb{C} \iff $ $\left|\langle u,\sigma(v) \rangle \right|$ is invariant for any $\sigma \in S_n$.

Note that for $n=2$ there is a simple counterexample $u=v=(1,-1)$. However I was unable to find any counterexample for $n \geq 3$.

**Update.** The conjecture is false in light of Matt's answer. However the known counterexamples are all highly "structural". Is there some way to identify all counterexamples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This (and specifically the $\Leftarrow$) is false: let
$$u = (-1,0,1)$$
$$v = (1, \omega, \omega^2)$$
where $\omega$ is a cube root of unity.

Comment: Interesting! I tried to extend this counterexample to larger $n$ but failed. Do you think  the conjecture in OP is incorrect for $n \geq 4$ as well?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a counterexample for any $n$ inspired by Matt's answer:
$$
u=(1,0,0,\dots,0) \\
v=(1,\omega,\omega^2,\dots,\omega^{n-1})
$$
where $\omega$ is the $n$th unit root.